# First Trigger- changing action

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a trigger that I wrote on before insert. I need to modify it to include before update but am not sure how to do it. The trigger copies what is in the picklist type field and copies it in the text area field Custom activity type.

Here is my before trigger:

```
trigger CustomActivity on Task (before insert) {
    for (Task t: Trigger.new){
        t.Custom_Activity_Type__c = t.Type;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just add before update to the list of events in trigger definition like `trigger CustomActivity on Tast (before insert,before update)`. As your code is so simple it will work in this way.

Answer (score 3):

It can be as simple as a few keystrokes.

From the [Documentation on Apex Trigger syntax](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_syntax.htm)

> To define a trigger, use the following syntax:
>
> ```
> trigger TriggerName on ObjectName (trigger_events) {
>    code_block
> }
> ```
>
> where trigger_events can be a comma-separated list of one or more of the following events:
>
> - before insert
> - before update
> - before delete
> - after insert
> - after update
> - after delete
> - after undelete

So the first line of your existing code

> trigger CustomActivity on Task (before insert) {

would become

> trigger CustomActivity on Task (before insert, before update) {

It looks like the trigger code that you have should be able to work in both contexts (before insert, and before update) just fine. If, however, you did need to run different code in different contexts, you can use some of the [Trigger Context Variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm) to help out.

```
if(Trigger.isInsert){
  // Code in here is only run on insert, either before insert or after insert
}

if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isUpdate){
  // Code in here would only run before update
}
```